# Avoid SQL Injection: Raw SQL in scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sql-injection

I have the following scope in my model:

```
scope :with_total_status, -> (date = Date.today) do
    select("agreements.*, (
      SELECT json_agg(statuses)
      FROM (
        SELECT
          ? AS calculated_status,
          SUM(?) AS total
        FROM agreement_installments
        WHERE agreement_installments.agreement_id = agreements.id
        GROUP BY calculated_status
      ) AS statuses
    ) agreement_status", "#{ AgreementInstallment.calculated_status_sql(date) }", "#{ AgreementInstallment.calculated_amount_remaining_or_paid(date) }")
  end
```

To avoid SQL injection, I have used `?` in two places as necessary. It doesn't work and give me any output. However, the following works correctly:

```
scope :with_total_status, -> (date = Date.today) do
    select("agreements.*, (
      SELECT json_agg(statuses)
      FROM (
        SELECT
          #{AgreementInstallment.calculated_status_sql(date)} AS calculated_status,
          SUM(#{AgreementInstallment.calculated_amount_remaining_or_paid(date)}) AS total
        FROM agreement_installments
        WHERE agreement_installments.agreement_id = agreements.id
        GROUP BY calculated_status
      ) AS statuses
    ) agreement_status")
  end
```

I am not really sure what is going wrong. Can you please give me the right direction for avoiding SQL injection and getting the correct output?

Comment: It's easy: To avoid SQL injection, **don't inject**. That is void using `#{...}` entirely in your queries. Always bind as placeholders.

Comment: Is this calculating column names? Do you have some kind of schema with column names that must be computed? If so that's a relational database failure. Instead of a heap of columns, make a relational table you can `JOIN`. This makes your query trivial.

Comment: It doesn't work because placeholders are for values not identifiers (column names, table names, ...) or SQL expressions; your placeholders will probably end up being replaced with single-quoted strings. So what does `AgreementInstallment.calculated_status_sql(date)` and `AgreementInstallment.calculated_amount_remaining_or_paid(date)` return?

Comment: Both of those are actually case statements. 
def self.calculated_status_sql(date, agreement_id = “agreements.id")
    %Q{
      CASE
        WHEN agreement_installments.amount = (
          SELECT sum(amount)
          FROM agreement_payments
          WHERE agreement_payments.agreement_installment_id = agreement_installments.id
        ) THEN 'paid'
        WHEN ——————
        ELSE 'future'
      END
    }
  end

Comment: AgreementInstallment.calculated_status_sql(date) and AgreementInstallment.calculated_amount_remaining_or_paid(date) have been used in several other places of the code. So, separate scopes were created for those.

Comment: Does it give an error? Can you put the sql that Rails is doing in your question?

Answer (score 0):

> Both of those are actually case statements. def self.calculated_status_sql(date, agreement_id = “agreements.id") %Q{ CASE WHEN agreement_installments.amount = ( SELECT sum(amount) FROM agreement_payments WHERE agreement_payments.agreement_installment_id = agreement_installments.id ) THEN 'paid' WHEN —————— ELSE 'future' END } end

In ActiveRecord, the `select` method does not take substitution arguments (maybe called bound variables) like the `where` method does.

You could build your subquery below

```
SELECT sum(amount) FROM agreement_payments
WHERE agreement_payments.agreement_installment_id = agreement_installments.id
```

using an AgreementPayment model (if you have one) as

```
sum_query = AgreementPayment.select('sum(amount)').where(agreement_installment_id: agreement_id)
```

then use `sum_query.to_sql` in the outer SQL statement you build.

Doing this might still end up injecting the SQL you build into the final SQL so it has risk and you will need to be careful.  However you are not taking raw user input and injecting it into your final SQL statement.  The input of the id value is properly sanitized this way.